# Snuff Bottle Calligraphy

Tags: translation

I recently inherited a modern snuff bottle collection that have what looks like old calligraphy on the back side. Can someone tell me what the calligraphy says, and maybe even the chop?

[image: characters on snuff bottle]

Answer (score 1):

it seems like: 岁在乙酉辛未月佳艺作， （from right to left）
the chop may be: 龙艺内书。

岁在乙酉辛未月 means it happened in 乙酉year （An ancient Chinese year recording method ）， 辛未month (also an ancient chinese month recording method).

Comment: if the year is “乙酉”, it should be “癸未” month  **乙庚之歲戊為頭**

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I am not very good at 六十甲子. thank you for your addition.  cheers

Comment: Thank you! So what year and/or month is that in "English"?

Comment: @Jmax 甲子cycles every 60 years. The last 乙酉 year was 2005. 癸未 would be ~July 7th - Aug 7th.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: 龙艺内"书" or "畫"? It looks like "田在一上" rather than "曰". Also, 佳"藝"(traditional form of 艺).

Comment: The symbol above 月 is only one character, so it can't be 辛未 and it looks like 春. 龙艺内书 should be 龙艺内画. The traditional characters of 书(書) and 画(畫) are often confusing.